Using Virtualbox, how to show menubar and statusbar in scaled mode?
I'm using Virtualbox and I want to use it in scale mode.
How to make Virtualbox
show the menu bar in scaled mode

and status bar

When you are in scaled mode,
the normal mode host menu

changes to the scaled mode host menu

And the difference is that the scaled host menu is lacking the view->menu/status bar menus
I have tried to create keyboard shortcuts to show menu/status bar

This works in normal mode, but does nothing in scaled mode.

Of course the usual answer to this question is "just install the guest addition"
In this case this is not an option. That would enable "seamless mode" where the resizing of the window, would change the resolution of the virtual monitor in the guest.
In normal more, you can change the scale factor

But even if you set it to "125% autoscale", the scaling factor remains fixed to 125% of original pixels. It will not stretch the image as you resize the window, example.

NOTE:
rightctrl+g is normal mode,
rightctrl+l is seamless mode, unavailable without guest additions
rightctrl+c is scaled mode
rightctrl+f is fullscreen mode which doesn't have the menu/status bars like scaled mode
